# Message "Please wait while IntelliSense and browsing information are updated." wasting my time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm working with very large project and after almost every change of the code the "Please wait" message with "Please wait while IntelliSense and browsing information are updated." text and slowly increasing number include files being processed (x/150000) for a few minutes.

Do I have something wrong in the configuration or why is the tool analyzing the include files again and again?

Comment: I dont want to put this as an answer but maybe you could try to turn Intellisence off. This is not an answer has it does'nt solve the problem but might just save you some time to find out what is wrong.

Comment: all right. I did the two separate changesets.